# Kernel panic - not syncing when using Ubuntu USB live

Tags: kernel, live-usb

I'm in serious need of some help.
I had ubuntu 15.04 on a dual boot with Windows 8. And then I wanted to install 16.04 and because I had some space issues, I decided to get 16.04 on a live USB and then boot through that. I used a something called UEFI USB boot instead of changing boot preferences for bios and ended up simply deleting the Linux partition (I knew then that's not the way to remove ubuntu but I thought I have a live USB to access my hard drive in any case).

Obviously now, normal boot would lead to grub rescue prompt.

I again boot through UEFI USB and started to install Ubuntu, somewhere in between a prompt mentioned that I'm using a UEFI system and if I continue I won't be able to use any OS installed on a BIOS system. So I did a hard reboot by cutting of the power and then change the preference in BIOS to boot from USB first.

And now my problem began. No matter what I do, try to install Ubuntu  or try Ubuntu without installing or a disk check ( these are the three out of four options that you get on booting from a live USB), I always get the same error screen.
"Kernel panic - not syncing : VFS: unable to mount root fa on unknown block (1,0) and around 10-15 more lines.
I am literally stuck at this. 
Help me out.

Comment: Any factory installed Windows 8/8.1/10 is inUEFI mode. As such always boot the Ubuntu installation media in the same way.

Comment: My experience is that Ubuntu Live on USB flash keys is problematic. Do you have a DVD drive on this computer? If so, burn the .iso to a DVD, boot the DVD, and you won't have any problem reinstalling. And @celticwarrior is correct, all OS should be installed the same... UEFI **or** not, but not both. Cheers, Al